# Android app with material cards crashes when run

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an app with material design cards as examplained here: http://goo.gl/7kC9Ej. 
My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/ tools"
             xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"             
            android:layout_width="match_parent"    
            android:layout_height="match_parent"       
            android:text="@string/hello_world"  />      

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The app compiles fine but crashes when I open it

Here's my error log: http://goo.gl/etne6I

Comment: can you post the error log,,,

Comment: http://goo.gl/etne6I

Comment: Please post our full xml code (some other xml which is related to these) becuase as per the error log you did not provide layout_width to any view

Comment: @sadiq added my entire main.XML file

Comment: `android:text="@string/hello_world"` should be within the textview.    Like this : `<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="@string/hello_world"/>`

Comment: @Ranjith did that, same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. You didnt specify width and height of the linear layout
2. You had placed text outside the `textview.`

Change it as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If this code is referenced in any other layout(by using `<include ...>` etc), ensure you have specified the `layout_width`,`layout_height` there too.

Comment: Are you getting the same exception?

Comment: @Cagentdog I have made some changes to the code. Try this out now.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add layout_height and layout_width in main linear layout. replace your xml code by below code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"    
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:orientation ="verticle">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"             
            android:layout_width="match_parent"    
            android:layout_height="match_parent"       
            android:text="@string/hello_world"  />      

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```